# Search: Problem with views:keyword in search

Tags: bug, search

I ran into this: For a certain user with many posts,

`user:4505`
https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A4505

search gives (16.09.2019) 812 hits. Augmenting the search with

`user:4505 views:..10000`
https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A4505+views%3A..10000

gives none! (same with slight variants). That looks like a bug.

Comment: Could you explain why you think it's a bug?  The results are merely telling you there are no posts by user 4505 with 10,000 or more views.  That's plausible.

Comment: No, ..10000 is abbreviated 0..10000 that is from zero to 10000 views. I would expect that to be close to 812

Comment: I don't follow.  Could you provide a link to a help page that explains your abbreviation?  BTW, if you think this is a bug, it's almost certainly system-wide and so your question belongs on SO meta rather than here.

Comment: Well, in other contexts it seems to work like that. Try `distributions views:0..100`

Comment: Which syntax are you actually using: "0..100" or "..100"?

Comment: For me those give the same result.

Comment: @whuber As per https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/searching, "To search for only questions that fall within a particular range for score, number of answers, or number of views, you can enter an upper or lower parameter, or a range." Also https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A4505+views%3A..10000 this page actually says `Search options: user 4505, views<= 10000`

Comment: Perhaps this is because user 4505 did not ask a single question?

Comment: @amoeba, you mean that the use of `views` implies `is:question`? It would be reasonable to expect it, when used with `user`, to look at the views related to *that users posts*, that is, the views on the questions to which he answered?

Comment: Thank you @amoeba.  I have the strong impression that `views` applies only to questions, too.  This makes a great deal of sense, *because a view count applies to the entire thread.*  It is therefore assigned to the question and not to the answers, all of which necessarily have smaller view counts than the thread.

Comment: Well, it makes sense as implementation detail, but for searches which include also answers, answers should inherit the views count from the question, if only because that breaks nothing and makes search more useful.

Comment: The problem of inheritance is that there is some problem with ambiguity of interpretation. The view-count of a question is not the view-count of an answer.  Example: an answer can be made to an very old question, and obviously that answer has not been viewed every time the question has been viewed (in addition we only know whether or not the webpage has been loaded, it is not an actual 'act of viewing' and for answers this discrepancy may be larger than for questions).

Comment: I can confirm that another user (me) who has never asked a question exhibits the same phenomenon as 4505 does.

Answer (score 5):

The views only relates to questions.

For instance try

[user:me views:...1000000](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+views%3A...1000000)

which in my case only returns my questions and not my answers.

So user 4505 must have never asked questions.

Using some more advanced query on the database (matching answers with the views for their parent questions) you could obtain the information you look for.